# How to trigger a method when two HTML elements have been filled?

Tags: html, angular

I have this HTML code where I have a `datepicker` and a `select` element. Right now I have a button which is connected to the method `checkAvailability()`

```
<div class ="d-flex flex-row bd-highlight mb-3">

    <div class = "form-froup row">
             
            <label class = "col-sm-2 col-form-label">Choose a date</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10"> 
                <input (change)="setCheckToFalse()" type ="date" class="form-control"[(ngModel)] = "Datum"
                    placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy">
                    </div>    
                        </div>
</div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Choose a location</label>
        <select (change)=Test() [(ngModel)]="selectedLocation" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
          <option *ngFor='let location of locations' [value]='location.Locatie'>{{location.Locatie}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
<button (click)="checkAvailability()" class="btn btn-primary">Check</button>
```

This is what happens when I click on said button:

```
checkAvailability()
  {
    this.res2 = {
      Datum: this.Datum,
      Locatie: this.selectedLocation
    }
    if(this.Datum != "")
    {
      this.Auth.checkAvailability(this.res2).subscribe(data =>
        {
          this.someint = data,
          this.anotherint = this.Capaciteit - this.someint,
          this.ruiid = this.RuimteId,
          {}
          if(this.anotherint > 0){ this.check = true}
        })
    }
    else( console.log("Choose a date!") )

  }
```

So basically when user chooses a date from the `datepicker` AND selects a location, the button connected to the `checkAvailability()` method executes the code inside it. What I want is for this to happen automatically, without the user having to click on the button.

So, I want the code in `checkAvailability()` to execute automatically every time the user chose a date AND a location.

Answer (score 0):

On change event check whether there is a value for the other control too. Suppose datepicker change event is fired check if the select value is present. if yes then fire the function else do nothing. Same for the other control.

Answer (score 0):

I can see you have added methods for `onchange`. Just call `checkAvailability()` inside `setCheckToFalse()` and `Test()` both, only when `this.Datum` and `this.selectedLocation` both have values.